# Enlarge font for search results

Tags: fonts

I'm running Kubuntu 18.04. How can I enlarge the font that is used to display Google search results?  System Settings/Fonts doesn't do it.

Comment: Ctrl+ will increase and Ctrl- will decrease the size of the fonts in a browser, if that is what you mean

Comment: The fonts are controlled by your browser - change the settings there